# How can I pre-render data which requires authentication in Next.js 13 app dir?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying build something similar to LinkedIn or Medium, where web crawlers (Google) can see a preview of page content, but you need to authenticate to see the juicy stuff.

My setup is as follows.

1. I have a Firestore collection of *user* documents. Each user has a `name` and an `email`.

   [image]
2. I want to generate a profile page for each user at the route `user/[id]`

   1. Authenticated users should see the user's name and email.

      [image]
   2. Unauthenticated users (including web crawlers) should see the user's name when they visit a user's profile.

      [image]

**Important Notes**

- You cannot request part of a Firestore document. You can either fetch all of it or none of it.
- My Firestore rules prevent you from fetching a user document unless you are authenticated. The rules look like this

  ```
  rules_version = '2';

  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
          match /users/{id} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
          }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

---

Is this pattern possible to achieve? Assuming it is, how can I go about it? Any examples would be great.

---

UPDATE: Here is some very obviously broken code to get the ball rolling.

```
// "use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth } from "../../../../firebase/firebase";


async function getUser(id) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "users", id);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  return docSnap.data();
}

// Define a server component that render's a user's profile
// The user's id should be included in the path like /user/123/
export default aysnc function User({ params }) {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null)
  const targetUser = await getUser(params.id)

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setAuthUser(user)
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: { targetUser.name }</p>
      { // Only render the email if the user is authenticated 
        authUser && <p>Email: { authUser.email }</p>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hopefully this makes it clear some of the challenges I'm facing such as

1. I *think* I need to build a server component, but I also need to make sure that the requesting user is authenticated - a task which requires client components.
2. How do I even fetch data from the server as if the server were an authenticated user?

Comment: It looks like you haven't made an attempt at solving this problem yet, is that correct?  Typically on Stack Overflow, you make an attempt, then post the code that isn't working the way you expect.  All you have right now is a set of requirements. Asking for examples is off-topic.

Comment: Hey thanks Doug. I *attempted* a solution in the form of lots of research and brainstorming. I usually post code in my questions here on SO, but I chose not to in this case because I didn't want to post something that is very obviously wrong for very obvious reasons, distracting readers from my actual question. That said, I'd be happy to post a very obviously wrong solution if you'd like :)

Comment: You should always post what you tried, and explain how that doesn't work the way you expect.  If it's so obviously wrong, then you'll receive a comment pointing that out, and you can try again with the new information you get. To be honest, what you're describing sounds like more than just a few lines of code. I also suggest explaining your use case in more detail, giving actual examples of data you're working with, and what the result should be.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added some code to my question. You also asked for examples of the data I'm working with, but did you notice I included that in my original post? I think the best way to describe my goal is, do a Google Search for "john smith linkedin". You will find lots of results, but none of them expose John's email address. To see his email, you need to authenticate with linkedin. Try to replicate this behavior (even on paper or in your head) with Next.js 13's app directory and server components and I think you'll see the challenge.

Comment: Pre-rendering anything that depends on the authenticated user state using the same URL is fairly futile isn't it? You can't pre-render content that changes based on the individual accessing it (otherwise you are serving it dynamically).  Also, what exactly is wrong with the code you've written?  Is there an error?  What's preventing it from working the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for continuing to look at this. I'm actually pretty close to solving my problem. The trick seems to be fetching the data using the Node.js admin SDK which can be initialized by a service account. You can keep the private key hidden from the client, but still fetch data from firestore without opening up the security rules. I'm still working through some stuff, but [this article](https://colinhacks.com/essays/nextjs-firebase-authentication) has been helpful (although it's based on Next.js before `app/` directory.)